# Three Numbers in Java

Tags: java, beginner, interview-questions, complexity

> Given three positive numbers A, B, and C. Find the number of positive
>   integers less than D that are divisible by either of A, B or C.
>
> **Input format**
>
> The 1st argument given is an Integer A. The 2nd argument given is an
>   Integer B. The 3rd argument given is an Integer C. The 4th argument
>   given is an Integer D.
>
> **Output Format**
>
> Return an Integer X, the number of positive integers that are
>   divisible by either of A, B, or C.
>
> Constraints
>
> 1 <= A, B, C, D <= 1e9
>
> For Example
>
> Input:
>
> A = 2
>
> B = 3
>
> C = 4
>
> D = 10
>
> Output:
>
> 6
>
> Explanation:
>
> positive numbers less than D that are divisible by either of A, B or C are    2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9

My approach:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Solution {
    public int solve(int A, int B, int C, int D) {
        BigInteger numDivA = BigInteger.valueOf((D - 1)/A);

        BigInteger numDivB = BigInteger.valueOf((D - 1)/B);

        BigInteger numDivC = BigInteger.valueOf((D - 1)/C);

        BigInteger newA = BigInteger.valueOf(A);

        BigInteger newB = BigInteger.valueOf(B);

        BigInteger newC = BigInteger.valueOf(C);

        BigInteger newD = BigInteger.valueOf(D);

        BigInteger limit = new BigInteger("1000000000");

        BigInteger lcmAB = (newA.divide(hcf(newA, newB))).multiply(newB);

        BigInteger lcmAC = (newC.divide(hcf(newA, newC))).multiply(newA);

        BigInteger lcmBC = (newB.divide(hcf(newB, newC))).multiply(newC);

        BigInteger lcmABC = lcmAB.divide(hcf(lcmAB,newC)).multiply(newC);     

        BigInteger numDivAB = newD.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).divide(lcmAB);

        BigInteger numDivBC = newD.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).divide(lcmBC);        

        BigInteger numDivAC = newD.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).divide(lcmAC);

        BigInteger numDivABC = newD.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).divide(lcmABC);                

        BigInteger numTotal = (((((numDivA.add(numDivB)).add(numDivC)).subtract(numDivAB)).subtract(numDivBC)).subtract(numDivAC)).add(numDivABC);

        return (numTotal.mod(limit)).intValue();
    }

    private BigInteger hcf (BigInteger a, BigInteger b) {

        BigInteger hcf = a.gcd(b);

        return hcf;
    }


}
```

I have the following questions with regards to the above code:

1. How can I further improve my approach?
2. Is there a better way to solve this question?
3. Are there any grave code violations that I have committed?
4. Can space and time complexity be further improved?
5. Have I gone too overboard by using **BigInteger**?

[Reference](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/three-numbers/)

Answer (score 2):

1e9 is only 1 billion, which will fit into a standard integer range of 2 billion some.

The `hcf` function is unexpected, because it's just a wrapper for `BigInteger`. I think just using the built in GCD function would be better than making your own method that calls a standard function. If it's critical to the algorithm understanding that we think of a highest common factor instead of a greatest common denominator, then keep the function. If you do keep it, though, use the full name instead of an abbreviation i.e. `private BigInteger highestCommonFactor`.

I looked at your code and expected to see a loop. I'm assuming you've worked out the math to do this without loops, which is good and probably more efficient. But, I don't really know how this would work, and would be worried someone else looking at the code would have the same problem. A code comment indicating what mathematical principles, or even the name of a theorem, would help immensely.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I understood the Math behind the question pretty fast. I was unable to solve it for higher values though. In the end, I used BigIntegers to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'll begin by answering the easiest question:

> Have I gone too overboard by using BigInteger?

Yes. The problem already ensures the variables are in an appropriate range because they are all <= 1e9 and the max value of an int is 2,147,483,647 or 2e9 ([source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1)), which is greater than 1e9. Using an int would be more appropriate.

But looking more deeply, I see you have used LCM as part of your algorithm, which is why you have become dependent on BigIntegers. I know LCM is not a necessary part of an algorithm, so I would use an alternative approach. But more on that later...

> How can I further improve my approach?

Note I'm using this section to critique your code without fundamentally changing the algorithm.

Stylistically, line breaks in between each line are unnecessary. Instead, I usually tend to group parts together that do similar things (e.g. assignment) or are multiple parts of a certain process (which could later be converted to a function if it's worthwhile, or if a library function already exists doing the thing I'm trying to do).

```
BigInteger limit = new BigInteger("1000000000");

//...

return (numTotal.mod(limit)).intValue();
```

This is quite a concerning pair of lines from a clean code perspective. Putting aside that `numtotal` should not be able to exceed 1e9 by the nature of the problem, i.e. if `numtotal` *were* able to exceed 1e9, you should not just modulus the value until it fits into the range. Instead, you should [throw an exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html) if the result is too large.

Without changing the algorithm, there are some other [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) improvements. The first thing I notice is `D - 1` is repeated throughout the code. I would probably assign this to a variable called `maxValue`. I also notice the structure of `VAR_1 / gcd(VAR_1, VAR_2) * VAR_2` to get LCM is suitable for an LCM function. Also concerning is the convolutions of A,B,C variable names; I would probably use arrays to allow for unbounded porting of the variables beyond three variables.

---

> Can space and time complexity be further improved?

In terms of efficiency, I think you're doing more a great deal more work than you need to.

My basic idea about how to approach this problem would be:

- Create an empty sorted set to store factors.
- Merge the set of factors from A, B, and C with the main set of factors.
- Remove all the factors that are >= D from the set of factors; this could be very efficient with binary search
- Return the length of the set of factors.

This approach is probably unnecessarily space inefficient; I can imagine there might be a way to iterate through A, B, and C's factors alternatively and simultaneously, removing duplicates as it goes along and stopping once D is reached. But as a first start, this approach limits the number of times I have to handle generating factors from a number, and allows a simple and clear base from which to build more complexity.

Answer (score -3):

Using BigInteger would increase the complexity of the program you can do it simpily.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! [While short answers are acceptable](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1479/120114) would you mind expanding this to give the OP more to work with? `simpily` is not an English word - did you mean `simply`? Are you saying that the OP should merely use `Integer` instead of `BigInteger`?